# Javascript String Split

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I've a String like following:

```
var str = '35,35,105,105,130,208,50,250';
```

I would like to split this string and get like this:

```
var arr = [[35,35],[105,105],[130,208],[50,250]];
```

I tried some ways, but none of them give me anything. I tried with looping to find the even comma position and split, but that doesn't seem good to me. Please give me some suggestion on this. I'm looking for `RegEx` Solution.

Comment: Does it *have* to be `RegEx`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possible approach:

```
'35,35,105,105,130,208,50,250'.match(/\d+,\d+/g).map(function(s) {
    return s.split(',');
});
```

Another crazy idea in one line:

```
JSON.parse('['+ '35,35,105,105,130,208,50,250'.replace(/\d+,\d+/g, '[$&]') +']');
```

Comment: a 2 dimensional array is needed

Comment: @ArunPJohny Yeah, I accidentally used `filter` instead of `map`.

Comment: This method will truncate the last value if the string contains an odd number of comma-separated values.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it.

```
var values = str.split(','),
    output = [];
while(values.length)
    output.push(values.splice(0,2));
```

If `str` contains an odd number of values, the last array in output will contain only one value using this method.